# Grails multi-user saving one at a time

Tags: grails

In a multi -user scenario, is there any way to prevent the other user/s in saving?

Suppose that I have multiple users trying to save the same period of time.

The current process we came up with is:

Check if the current period is already taken. If true, do not save. else, save.

but the checker cannot get anything from the database whenever we try to save at the same time. thus, both instance is successfully save.

Test Scenario:

User1: Selected date1

User2: Selected date1

***both users submit form***

1 user should save successfully and 1 user should be blocked.

Comment: Which database you are using? Is It same field in database where you are saving the value from multiple users?

Comment: User 1 starts at 00:00:00:00 user 2 starts at 00:00:00:00 down to the milliseconds define which is user1 and which is user2 ? when you have decided that part you can proceed

Comment: You can look into using .lock mechanism although when you start a transaction the object increments versions so you could check to see what the version is as 1 form of a test - the object also gets dirty you can do is instance.isDirty() but that typically is bound to your current transaction and I have found straight after a save it tells you if there was a change - the issue here is what if user a is making a valid change and so is user b do you not wish to capture both if so you are asking the wrong question and maybe need to look at .withNewTransaction